# MacBook pro retina 15" mid 2015 - two monitors 4k@60Hz

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I'm considering to buy the above mentioned MacBook with the Intel Iris Pro Graphics and **without** the additional AMD graphic card.

Now my question is whether this configuration supports connecting **two** external monitors with 4k resolution @60 HZ or not. Moreover SST or MST support will be helpful, too. 
I'm thankful for every source link provided.

Comment: It says that but when I go to display there isn't any "arrangement" option to do split screen. anyone have any ideas? I'm lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Everymac:](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.8-15-iris-only-mid-2015-retina-display-specs.html)

> *This model supports a simultaneous maximum resolution up to 3840x2160 on two external displays via Thunderbolt 2. Alternately, it can
>   support a single display up to 3840x2160 via Thunderbolt 2 and a
>   single 1080p display at up to 60 Hz, 3840x2160 at 30 Hz, or 4096x2160
>   at 24 Hz via HDMI.