# Two thunderbolt ports on my mid-2015 MacBook Pro how do I configure one monitor to be in mirroring mode and the other in extended desktop mode?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

So its my understanding that I can have two flatscreen monitors as long as I use the right cables and each thunderbolt on my Mac will connect to each monitor for a total of 2 monitors and as long they meet the specifications listed in this post:
[MacBook pro retina 15" mid 2015 - two monitors 4k@60Hz](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261144/macbook-pro-retina-15-mid-2015-two-monitors-4k60hz)

However, how do I connect them to ensure it extends my workspace with different apps and windows on each display where I can move a document or application from one screen to the other? In other words, how do I configure one monitor to be in mirroring mode and the other in extended desktop mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to configure such a setup with the standard macOS GUI.

However, I think you might have understood something, and you do not really need such as setup.

If you want to be able to have 2 separate, external, 4k@60Hz displays that you can use for working with various windows - while the laptop lid is closed - then you do not need such a setup. You'll just need to make sure that "Mirror Displays" is not checked in the Display settings in System Preferences.

If you want to be able to have 3 seperate displays, where one is the internal laptop display and then 2 external, 4k@60 Hz displays that you can use for working with various windows - then you do not need such a setup. You'll just need to make sure that "Mirror Displays" is not checked in the Display settings in System Preferences.

If what you really want is to have the laptops display and a secondary, separate workspace that is mirrored between the two external displays - that's not achievable with the standard macOS GUI. However, that would also be a quite uncommon setup.

Comment: It's the first setup you quoted, the 2 separate external for working with various windows while laptop is closed that I am wanting to achieve. That's how it was at my old job, but back then we used Apple monitors.

Comment: That’s the default setup - no problem there. Just plugin the monitors.